# Is there a function that cold help me summarize time intervals with duplicate values in some of them in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have a table that looks like this:

[image: Raw data]

I want to make it look like this:

[image: Summarized form]

I tried with =unique() formula, but it doesn't work, since I quantities that duplicate in different time intervals. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Query( {range} , "select max([end interval]), quantity",1)
```

Where the range is the raw data.

Answer (score 0):

I would use offset ranges to detect when there is a change in quantity:

For start time

```
=ArrayFormula(query(
if((indirect("D1:d"&counta(D:D)-1)<>indirect("d2:D"&counta(D:D)))*(indirect("d2:D"&counta(D:D))<>0),indirect("A2:A"&counta(A:A)),""),
"select Col1 where Col1 is not null format Col1 'hh:mm'",0))
```

For end time

```
=ArrayFormula(query(
if((indirect("D3:d"&counta(D:D)+1)<>indirect("d2:D"&counta(D:D)))*(indirect("d2:D"&counta(D:D))<>0),indirect("b2:b"&counta(B:B)),""),
"select Col1 where Col1 is not null format Col1 'hh:mm'",0))
```

For quantity

```
=ArrayFormula(query(
if((indirect("D1:d"&counta(D:D)-1)<>indirect("d2:D"&counta(D:D)))*(indirect("d2:D"&counta(D:D))<>0),indirect("d2:d"&counta(D:D)),""),
"select Col1 where Col1 is not null",0))
```

[image]